# Call a JavaScript function by hitting enter in a textbox without global events of jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onkeypress

I am working on a project with the goal of learning, and I am avoiding jQuery thus far to learn as much JavaScript as possible.  I have been successfully using onkeypress to determine whether or not enter was hit in a textbox or textarea, but after adding a searchbar on me website, I discovered that events like onkeypress are global (ie. hitting enter in the search bar activates my 'send message' textarea).

I am also using AJAX, and thus I do not want a simple form submit.  I am also hoping to use a textarea, since I am after multiple lines (so that more text is visible).

Under these constraints, is this reasonable to do without using jQuery?  If so, how can I do it?  Other answers on the site simply point to jQuery.

Thanks,

Paragon

Edit: I was asked for code, so here is the relevant HTML and JavaScript.  Here is one of the inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" onkeypress="return activate(event, this.value);"/>
```

Here is the javascript to go along with it:

```
function activate(e, message)
{   
    if (isNotEnter(e))
    {   
        return true;
    }   
    else // ie. enter was pressed
    {   
        // only proceed to search() if message is not empty
        if (message.length >= 1)
        {   
            search();
        }   
        return false;
    }   
}
```

And the function isNotEnter():

```
function isNotEnter(e)
{   
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    {   
        return false;
    }   
    else
    {   
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are capturing the key event on `document`, not your input element specifically.

So find something like `document.onkeypress = function() { ... }` and replace with `document.getElementById('your-input').onkeypress = function() { ... }`.

If you can't find that code, you may be using `addEventListener`, so find `document.addEventListener('keypress', function() { ... }, false);`

#### Update

You want to avoid inline event handlers. [Google `addEventListener()`](http://google.com/search?q=javascript%20addeventlistener) (and you will also see why we need `attachEvent()` for < IE9).

Also, you generally don't want to name functions as negating something, e.g. your example `isNotEnter()`. You should flip its function around and call it `isEnter()`, so you can use the negation operator for *is not enter*, e.g. `! isEnter()`.

Comment: My code is now posted above.  As you can see, I'm calling onkeypress from the HTML input element itself, which is why I thought onkeypress would not be global.

Comment: Thank you for driving me to use jQuery! It seems that IE doesn't support addEventListener().  While I don't use IE, I obviously don't want others to have issues.

Comment: @Paragon You need to use `attachEvent()` for our good friends < IE9. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 3):

You should use jquery because it is awesome, easy to learn, gets rid of browser issues, etc.

If you are totally against it though, it can be done with pure JS. It would help if you show your code, but you are probably binding the onkeypress event to the document when you should be binding it to the input.

```
$("#search").keypress(function()
{
//do function here, use this to refer to the element
});
```

Comment: If the OP is learning JavaScript, we ought to steer them away from inline event handlers and the `javascript:` pseudo protocol (which is unnecessary in your example anyway).

Comment: Okay, I've edited to include some of my code.  I should specifically note that if this task is outrageously hard to do in JavaScript alone, I'm not against using jQuery.  I'm just trying to learn as much as I can.

Comment: great, I really think jQuery is one of the easiest code libraries to learn. I edited above to show jquery way.